# Generating zonal stats for multiple rasters using rasterstats

Tags: python, zonal-statistics, rasterstats

I'm trying to generate the zonal stats for multiple rasters without using ArcPy.

I've successfully obtained results using rasterstats for one image and one polygon. I  would like to use the same polygon but many rasters. My code is below and not working. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Lista_raster = [
   "NDVI_2019-05-05.tiff", "NDVI_2019-05-25.tiff", "NDVI_2019-06-04.tiff", 
   "NDVI_2019-06-09.tiff", "NDVI_2019-06-14.tiff", "NDVI_2019-06-19.tiff",
   "NDVI_2019-06-24.tiff", "NDV_2019-05-05.tiff"
]
for raster in Lista_raster:
    stats = zonal_stats("Pivo_4_wgs.shp", Lista_raster,
            stats=['min', 'max', 'median', 'majority', 'std'],  
            geojson_out=True)
result = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": stats}
import json
with open('lista.geojson', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(result, outfile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice this part of your code:

```
for raster in Lista_raster:
    stats = zonal_stats("Pivo_4_wgs.shp", Lista_raster,  # <---here
```

You're passing the entire list for each iteration of your loop. Try passing the the element of the iterator instead:

```
for raster in Lista_raster:
    stats = zonal_stats("Pivo_4_wgs.shp", raster, ...
```

You're also only writing a single file at the end of the loop, instead of a file for each result. So your code becomes:

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

Lista_raster = [
   "NDVI_2019-05-05.tiff", "NDVI_2019-05-25.tiff", "NDVI_2019-06-04.tiff", 
   "NDVI_2019-06-09.tiff", "NDVI_2019-06-14.tiff", "NDVI_2019-06-19.tiff",
   "NDVI_2019-06-24.tiff", "NDV_2019-05-05.tiff"
]

for raster in Lista_raster:
    stats = zonal_stats("Pivo_4_wgs.shp", raster,
            stats=['min', 'max', 'median', 'majority', 'std'],  
            geojson_out=True)
    result = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": stats}

    outname = Path(raster).name + '.geojson'
    with open(outname, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(result, outfile)
```